# div height to take remaining height

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS issue. I think this is simple and usual but I know why I can not achieve this.

I am trying to get the div height to take the remaining height of another div.

I have 3 divs

```
 <div id='div1'>
    <div id='div2'>
    </div>
       <div id='div3'>

   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #div1{position:fixed;top:0px;right:0px;width:250px;height:100%;}
 #div2{width:100%;height:250px;float:left;}
 #div3{}   // now I want this div to take the remaining height with only CSS and I don't want to use flex.
```

I think remaining width takes a div by this code.

CSS

```
{width:auto;overflow:hidden;}
```

This takes all the remaining width of div but the same code doesn't work with height.

Please suggest me something with this.

Comment: #div3 {height:100%;}  should work, unless im mistaken.

Comment: @Zapp It will not work as the upper div is also there which is float left..

Comment: @Johannes No div2 and div3 are float left and both are under div1

Comment: @Johannes oh sorry please see the updated one

Comment: [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). It's not easy, but there are many tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

```
height: calc(100% - 250px);
```

You could use this for `div3` in your css. Hope this helps (:

Comment: actually the div2 max-height is 250px and min-height 100px so it is also not known that what will be its height

Answer (score 0):

You should try the CSS as seen below for #div3 (I have improved answer because now #div3 is not in #div2 but actually #div2 and #div3 is in #div1)

```
#div3 {
 width:100%;
 height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
#div1 {
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

#div3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

DIV 3 gets a very high height value, but is cut off automatically by `overflow: hidden`

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXjBJR